# Time series decimation benchmark: Dask vs Vaex

Tags: python, numpy, dask, vaex

I currently use Vaex to generate binned data for histograms and to decimate big time-series data. Essentially I reduce millions of time series points into a number of bins and compute the mean & max & min for each bin. I would like to compare [Vaex](http://vaex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) (reading HDF files)  and Dask (reading Parquet files) and to keep it 'out-of-core memory.

#### Update 3 (I've deleted previous updates):

Dask is 30% faster than Vaex for the 1st run but then Vaex 4.5 times faster with repeated runs. I believe Vaex gets this speed-up through memory mapping.  Is there a way in Dask to improve the execution times of the repeated runs?

First, create some random data and generate some files, warning: this will generate 1.5GB of data.

```
import numpy as np
import vaex as vx
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
import os

#cwd = os.getcwd() # Change this to your directory for path to save hdf and parquet files 
cwd = r'F:\temp\DaskVaexx' # Write files to this directory.  Use a fast SSD for fast read calculations in Dask/Vaex

### Create random data
size = 20000000 # number of rows
scale = 1.
scaleLocal = 20
np.random.seed(0)
x_data = np.arange(size)
y_data = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(size)  * scale) + np.random.randn(size) * scaleLocal

np.random.seed(1)
scaleLocal2 = 3
y_data2 = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(size)  * scale) + np.random.randn(size) * scaleLocal2
df = pd.DataFrame({'t': x_data.astype(np.float32),'Channel1' : y_data.astype(np.float32),'Channel2' : y_data2.astype(np.float32)})
# df

#Create Dask dataframe
dask_df = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=1)

# Creat a Vaex dataset from pandas and then export to hdf5
dataVX = vx.from_pandas(df)
dataVX.export_hdf5(os.path.join(cwd, 'randomData.hdf'))

# Create a parquet folder and files from dask dataframe
dask_df.to_parquet(os.path.join(cwd, 'randomData.parquet'))

# Create a hdf file from dask dataframe
#dask_df.to_hdf(os.path.join(cwd, 'randomDataDask.hdf'), '/data')
```

Now do the Vaex and Dask processing:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import dask.array as da
import vaex as vx
import dask
import time
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#

bins = 1000
minLimit = 0
maxLimit = 1000000
timeArrayName = 't'
column = 'Channel1'

# filePath = os.getcwd() # location of hdf and parquet data
filePath = r'F:\temp\DaskVaexx' # location of hdf and parquet data

# ------------------------------
# Vaex code

startTime = time.time()

dataVX = vx.open(os.path.join(filePath,r'randomData.hdf'))

#Calculate the min & max of a columnar dataset for each bin
minMaxVaexOutputArray = dataVX.minmax(column, binby=[timeArrayName],  shape=(bins,), limits=[minLimit,maxLimit])

VaexResults_df = pd.DataFrame(data = minMaxVaexOutputArray, columns = ['min','max'])

#Calculate the mean of a columnar dataset for each bin
VaexResults_df['mean'] = dataVX.mean(column, binby=[timeArrayName],  shape=(bins,), limits=[minLimit, maxLimit]) 

print('Vaex hdf computation time: ' + str(time.time() - startTime))

# dataVX.close_files() # option to close down the opened Vaex dataset
# ------------------------------

# ------------------------------
# Dask computation
startTime = time.time()

# Read parquet file or folder of files
parquet_dd = dd.read_parquet(os.path.join(filePath,r'randomData.parquet'))  

# Create a virtual column which assigns integers to the time signal according to its assigned bin
parquet_dd['timeGroups'] = parquet_dd[timeArrayName].where((parquet_dd[timeArrayName]>=minLimit) & (parquet_dd[timeArrayName]<maxLimit))   // ((maxLimit - minLimit ) / bins)

# Groupby using the virtual column
df3 = parquet_dd[column].groupby(parquet_dd['timeGroups']).aggregate(['min', 'max', 'mean'])

#Execute Dask and return results to a Pandas Dataframe
DaskResults_df = dask.compute(df3)[0]

print('Dask with parquet computation time: ' + str(time.time() - startTime))
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the data? How did you convert from hdf to parquet, and did you try dask with the hdf directly?

Comment: @mdurant I have not tried dask with hdf directly.  I have updated the post to generate some random data with a decent amount of rows.  I would really appreciate you looking into this.

Comment: Running your code, I get an output for vaex of size (3, 1000) but the three dask outputs are pandas series of size (1000000,).

Comment: @mdurant .  Thanks for having a look at this. I have modified the code and updated the post above.  I needed to add a 'where' filter on the groupby Dask command to get the same output array size. I have editted the comments above to update the new relative execution times.  This is the important one "Dask is 30% faster than Vaex for the 1st run but then Vaex 4.5 times faster with repeated runs. I believe Vaex gets this speed-up through memory mapping.  Is there a way in Dask to improve the execution times of the repeated runs? "

Comment: You could try `dask.persist()` run on various of the intermediate dataframes.

Comment: Also, I suppose you are using the default scheduler, but you can try with the distributed one, sometimes better even on a single machine.

Comment: Thanks, I will try your suggestions.  Also, I have found that Dask is quicker with HDF5 than Parquet in this case.

Comment: It sounds like you are in a good position to write an answer to your own question with a summary of your findings.